# Oracle SQL: How to get rolling SUM of only last 3 months?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the following dataset, wherein I want to check if a part has the qty for the last 3 months and sum them up. For example, for the part `ABC`, for the month of `01-MAY-23`, the last 3 months in the vdate column are `01-MAY-23, 01-APR-23, 01-MAR-23`. Since, these 3 months exist, I want to add the quantities as `50 + 40 + 30 = 120`. The same does not exist for the part `DEF`, so that part won't appear in the output.

`data`

```
| PART | VDATE     | MONTH     | QTY |
|------|-----------|-----------|-----|
| ABC  | 01-JAN-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 10  |
| ABC  | 01-FEB-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 20  |
| ABC  | 01-MAR-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 30  |
| ABC  | 01-APR-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 40  |
| ABC  | 01-MAY-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 50  |
| ABC  | 01-MAR-23 | 01-JUN-23 | 25  |
| ABC  | 01-APR-23 | 01-JUN-23 | 35  |
| ABC  | 01-MAY-23 | 01-JUN-23 | 45  |
| ABC  | 01-JUN-23 | 01-JUN-23 | 55  |
| DEF  | 01-APR-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 25  |
| DEF  | 01-MAY-23 | 01-MAY-23 | 35  |
```

`Output`

```
| PART | MONTH     | QTY |
|------|-----------|-----|
| ABC  | 01-MAY-23 | 120 |
| ABC  | 01-JUN-23 | 135 |
```

`sql`

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-JAN-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 10 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-FEB-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 20 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 30 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 40 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 50 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 25 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 35 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 45 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 55 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'DEF' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 25 qty FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'DEF' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 35 qty FROM dual
)

SELECT *
FROM data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data you posted

```
SQL> WITH data AS (
  2      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-JAN-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 10 qty FROM dual UNION
  3      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-FEB-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 20 qty FROM dual UNION
  4      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 30 qty FROM dual UNION
  5      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 40 qty FROM dual UNION
  6      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 50 qty FROM dual UNION
  7      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 25 qty FROM dual UNION
  8      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 35 qty FROM dual UNION
  9      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 45 qty FROM dual UNION
 10      SELECT 'ABC' part, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-JUN-23') month, 55 qty FROM dual UNION
 11      SELECT 'DEF' part, TO_DATE('01-APR-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 25 qty FROM dual UNION
 12      SELECT 'DEF' part, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') vdate, TO_DATE('01-MAY-23') month, 35 qty FROM dual
 13  )
```

This might be one option:

```
 14  select part, month, sum(qty) qty
 15  from data
 16  where vdate between add_months(month, -2) and month
 17  group by part, month
 18  having count(*) = 3;

PAR MONTH            QTY
--- --------- ----------
ABC 01-MAY-23        120
ABC 01-JUN-23        135

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY part, month
  ORDER BY vdate
  MEASURES
    SUM(qty) AS qty
  PATTERN (consecutive_months{2} last_month)
  DEFINE 
    consecutive_months AS ADD_MONTHS(vdate, 1) = NEXT(vdate),
    last_month AS vdate = month
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (part, vdate, month, qty) AS
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 10 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 20 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 30 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 40 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 50 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 25 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 35 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 45 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2023-06-01', DATE '2023-06-01', 55 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEF', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 25 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEF', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-01', 35 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PART | MONTH | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 120 |
| ABC | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 135 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t_XyGTLl)

Comment: This is something quite new for me. Thanks for the solution!